# modify all key value of each objects in arrray JavaScript | modify array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
];
```

I want to change the value of the desc of all objects in an array.
How I can change this?

Comment: Change it to what?

Comment: Title is `modify key value` but question is `I want to change the value of the desc`. I guess you want the later one?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to mutate the original array:

```js
const input = [
  {
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png",
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png",
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png",
  },
];

input.forEach(x => x.desc = 'someThingElse');

console.log(input);
```

If you need to keep the original array as is, and create a new one:

```js
const input = [
  {
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png",
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png",
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png",
  },
];

const result = input.map(x => ({ ...x, desc: 'someThingElse' }));

console.log(result);
```

Of course, you can add some logic inside the callbacks in order to set a specific value to every item in the array.